# Beanstalkd/Pheanstalk for PHPMailer on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmailer, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I would like to implement a queuing mechanism for sending out email via PHPMailer on Amazon EC2. I have set up Beanstalkd correctly on the server and can access it via a console. The mail doesn't seem to go through (trying the various combinations of sample code). In addition do I need to set up a cron job also that would call one of the producer or consumer files?

Does anyone have working code for sending out email via phpmailer/pheanstalk please for Amazon EC2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beanstalkd is great, and I use it myself, however, don't use it for this; It's reinventing the wheel in a bad way. Instead, install a local mail server such as postfix and get that to do your queuing for you. This is also much, much simpler, faster, and easier to control. Email servers are built for managing queues, and they are extremely good at it.

Before you do so, get your mail sending script working – there's no point in even attempting to get something more complex working until you've done that. Also be aware that sending email from EC2 is difficult – Amazon wants you to use their SES service rather than sending directly – you may find sending is blocked altogether. Read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide to see how to diagnose that.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks a lot for the quick response. To clarify:
1. PHPMailer I have tested and working fine. I am using SES.
2. Current code requires confirmation that mail is sent before the user can progress. Concerned that it will be a bottle-neck in the future.
Would it make sense to add Postfix between PHPMailer and SES?

Comment: You can put postfix between PHP and SES, but only if you're submitting messages over SMTP (I think SES has an HTTP interface too). You can submit a message to local postfix in just a few milliseconds, freeing up your user connection. It will then deal with relaying the message into SES, dealing with retries, throttling, message/connection rate limits, outages etc all automatically because SMTP is designed to do exactly this without you having to configure anything special.

Comment: thanks again. Will take your advice and try that. Although secretly, would love to try and get beanstalkd working too :)